# Deserializing a byte[] from C# Tool in Node.js

Tags: c#, json, node.js, express, serialization

I have inherited a C# tool that sends a serialized byte array of meeting data to an online calendar application. The online calendar uses a node.js API. My problem is that the serialized byte array is not getting parsed correclty by node.js (IE, in express the req.body object is empty). I am look for either a way to send the data so it can be parsed by Node.js, or a parser in Node.js that can handle c# byte arrays. It is JSON formatted. Here is the code that sends the request:

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(reallyPost, Formatting.None);
byte[] postThisz = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(json);
byte[] response = wc.UploadData(siteUrl, postThisz);
```

At the moment I'm simply trying to log the data. The route is caught here:

```
app.post('/remotePost', api.remotePost);
```

which uses this controller:

```
module.exports.remotePost = function (req, res) {
  console.log(req);
  console.log(req.body);
  sendJsonResponse(res, 200, "remote posted.");
};
```

The req.body gets populated by my parsing middleware:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

However this cannot handle the byte array sent by the C# program. I can solve this either by finding a parser that will handle the C# POST correctly (byte[] type), or finding a C# module that can make a post containing something of the format that JSON.stringify() returns.

Comment: Does this mean I should use something other than MyWebClient().UploadData() to send the request? Seems like this method insists on binary data.

Comment: Ah, sorry, looks like I misread. The only issue here that I can see is that you're using `Encoding.ASCII` instead of something like `Encoding.UTF8`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's advisable to change the encoding to utf8

```
 Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);
```

Then, you should also set the appropriate headers before upload

```
 wc.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf8");
```

Comment: This successfully makes the request show up in req.body, however it is not parsed and entirely unusable. For instance, in place of an actual JSON object it shows [Object object] (The string)

Comment: Ok, when you smth in body, it means transport and parsing was successful. I think smth wrong is with your `string json`, could you try to replace it with `string json = "[123]"`?

Comment: Please edit your answer to read "charset=utf-8". Otherwise, it is correct, I was reading Node's output wrong.